# Database problem when changing from localhost to hosted version

Tags: php, mysql

I am coding a website, that needs a connection to an MySQL database, when I am connecting locally everything works as intended, but when changing to my database hosted on one.com, I get the message: `"Warning: mysqli_fetch_field() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given[...]"`.

I checked if the connection to the database works and it does, so changing the database credentials is not the problem.

What could be the problem?

### Edit

I seem to have figured out what's causing the problem, but I don't understand why. There is an error in the SQL query:

```
       $TOPS = "Create Temporary Table a_O
            
         SELECT distinct(ve.FAB_ID) AS US, vi.FAB_ID as VS
                  FROM 06_fuehrt_aus ve
                  JOIN 06_fuehrt_aus vi
                  USING (OPS)
                  JOIN 06_fab vir
                  ON (vi.FAB_ID = vir.FAB_ID)

                  JOIN 06_fab ver
                  ON(ve.FAB_ID = ver.FAB_ID)
                  
                  WHERE ve.FAB_ID != vi.FAB_ID
                  AND ve.FAB_ID = \"".$FAB."\" Limit 100;";
```

The statement works locally and it also works hosted, until I add

```
   JOIN 06_fab ver
    ON(ve.FAB_ID = ver.FAB_ID)
```

### Edit2:

```
<?php
    $TPER = "Create Temporary Table a_P SELECT distinct(ve.FAB_ID) AS Ursprungsstation, vi.FAB_ID as Vergleichsstation, count(ve.PER_ID) as Personal_ID
                              FROM 06_hat_personal_fab ve
                              JOIN 06_hat_personal_fab vi
                              USING (PER_ID)
                              JOIN 06_fab ver
                              ON (ve.FAB_ID = ver.FAB_ID)
                              JOIN 06_fab vir
                              ON (vi.FAB_ID = vir.FAB_ID)
                                           
                              WHERE ve.FAB_ID != vi.FAB_ID
                              AND vir.IK=ver.IK
                              AND ve.FAB_ID = \"" . $FAB . "\" GROUP BY Ursprungsstation, Vergleichsstation Limit 200;";
    mysqli_query($conn, $TPER);


    $TuPER = "Create Temporary Table bc_P 
                    SELECT distinct(ve.FAB_ID) AS Station, count(ve.PER_ID) as Menge
                        FROM 06_hat_personal_fab ve
                        JOIN 06_fab vi 
                        USING (FAB_ID)
                        WHERE vi.IK = \"".$IK."\" GROUP BY Station LIMIT 20;";

mysqli_query($conn, $TuPER); 

//Create Temporary Tables for 06_behandelt
    $TICD = "Create Temporary Table a_I
                SELECT distinct(ve.FAB_ID) AS Ursprungsstation, vi.FAB_ID as Vergleichsstation, count(ve.ICD) as BehandlungID
                                            FROM 06_behandelt ve
                                            JOIN 06_behandelt vi
                                            USING (ICD)
                                            JOIN 06_fab ver
                                            ON (ve.FAB_ID = ver.FAB_ID)
                                            JOIN 06_fab vir
                                            ON (vi.FAB_ID = vir.FAB_ID)
                                            
                                            WHERE ve.FAB_ID != vi.FAB_ID
                                            and ve.Anzahl > 0
                                            and vi.Anzahl > 0
                                            AND vir.IK=ver.IK
                                            AND ve.FAB_ID =\"".$FAB."\" GROUP BY Ursprungsstation, Vergleichsstation Limit 100;";

mysqli_query($conn, $TICD);

    $TuICD = "Create Temporary Table bc_I
                SELECT distinct(ve.FAB_ID) AS Station, count(ve.ICD) as Menge
                        FROM 06_behandelt ve
                        JOIN 06_fab vi 
                        USING (FAB_ID)
                        WHERE 
                        Anzahl > 0
                        AND vi.IK =\"".$IK."\" GROUP BY Station Limit 100";

mysqli_query($conn, $TuICD); 

//Create Temporary Tables for 06_fuehrt_aus
    $TOPS = "Create Temporary Table a_O
                SELECT distinct(ve.FAB_ID) AS Ursprungsstation, vi.FAB_ID as Vergleichsstation, count(ve.OPS) as OPCode
                                              FROM 06_fuehrt_aus ve
                                              JOIN 06_fuehrt_aus vi
                                              USING (OPS)
                                              JOIN 06_fab ver
                                              ON (ve.FAB_ID = ver.FAB_ID)
                                              JOIN 06_fab vir
                                              ON (vi.FAB_ID = vir.FAB_ID)
                                              
                                              WHERE ve.FAB_ID != vi.FAB_ID
                                              and ve.Anzahl > 0
                                              and vi.Anzahl > 0
                                              AND vir.IK=ver.IK
                                              AND ve.FAB_ID = \"".$FAB."\" GROUP BY Ursprungsstation, Vergleichsstation Limit 100;";

mysqli_query($conn, $TOPS);
    $TuOPS = "Create Temporary Table bc_O
                SELECT distinct(ve.FAB_ID) AS Station, count(ve.OPS) as Menge
                          FROM 06_fuehrt_aus ve
                          JOIN 06_fab vi 
                          USING (FAB_ID)
                          WHERE 
                          Anzahl > 0
                          AND vi.IK =\"".$IK."\"GROUP BY Station Limit 100;";
mysqli_query($conn, $TuOPS);

//Create Temporary Tables for 06_ml_fab
    $TML = "Create Temporary Table a_M
            SELECT distinct(ve.FAB_ID) AS Ursprungsstation, vi.FAB_ID as Vergleichsstation, count(ve.ML_Schluessel) as ML
                                              FROM 06_ml_fab ve
                                              JOIN 06_ml_fab vi
                                              USING (ML_Schluessel)
                                              JOIN 06_fab ver
                                              ON (ve.FAB_ID = ver.FAB_ID)
                                              JOIN 06_fab vir
                                              ON (vi.FAB_ID = vir.FAB_ID)
                                              
                                              WHERE ve.FAB_ID != vi.FAB_ID
                                              AND vir.IK=ver.IK
                                              AND ve.FAB_ID = \"".$FAB."\" GROUP BY Ursprungsstation, Vergleichsstation Limit 100;";
mysqli_query($conn, $TML);
    
    $TuML = "Create Temporary Table bc_M
                SELECT distinct(ve.FAB_ID) AS Station, count(ve.ML_Schluessel) as Menge
                          FROM 06_ml_fab ve
                          JOIN 06_fab vi 
                          USING (FAB_ID)
                          WHERE vi.IK = \"".$IK. "\" GROUP BY Station Limit 100;";
mysqli_query($conn, $TuML);


//SELECT for Jaccard PER_ID

if ($SM == "Jaccard") {

//Temporary PER Jaccard 
                        $PER_J = "Create Temporary Table P_J
                        Select a.Ursprungsstation, a.Vergleichsstation, (Personal_ID/(b.Menge+c.Menge-Personal_ID)) as Jaccard_PER
                                    FROM bc_P b
                                    JOIN a_P a                                          
                                    on (Station=Ursprungsstation)
                                    JOIN bc_P c
                                    on (c.Station=a.Vergleichsstation)
                                    Limit 100;";
                                    
                                    $R_PER_J = mysqli_query($conn, $PER_J);
//Temporary ICD Jaccard 
                        $ICD_J = "Create Temporary Table I_J
                        Select a.Ursprungsstation, a.Vergleichsstation, (BehandlungID/(b.Menge+c.Menge-BehandlungID)) as Jaccard_ICD
                                    FROM bc_I b
                                    JOIN a_I a                                          
                                    on (Station=Ursprungsstation)
                                    JOIN bc_I c
                                    on (c.Station=a.Vergleichsstation)
                                    Limit 100;";    
                                    
                                    $R_ICD_J = mysqli_query($conn, $ICD_J); 

//Temporary OPS Jaccard 

                        $OPS_J = "Create Temporary Table O_J 
                        Select a.Ursprungsstation, a.Vergleichsstation, (OPCode/(b.Menge+c.Menge-OPCode)) as Jaccard_OPS
                                    FROM bc_O b
                                    JOIN a_O a                                          
                                    on (Station=Ursprungsstation)
                                    JOIN bc_O c
                                    on (c.Station=a.Vergleichsstation)
                                    Limit 100;";                

                                    $R_OPS_J = mysqli_query($conn, $OPS_J);
//Temporary ML Jaccard

                        $ML_J = "Create Temporary Table M_J
                                    Select a.Ursprungsstation, a.Vergleichsstation, (ML/(b.Menge+c.Menge-ML)) as Jaccard_ML
                                    FROM bc_M b
                                    JOIN a_M a                                          
                                    on (Station=Ursprungsstation)
                                    JOIN bc_M c
                                    on (c.Station=a.Vergleichsstation)
                                    Limit 100;";

                                    $R_ML_J = mysqli_query($conn, $ML_J);

    // Connect einzelne Jaccard Abfragen

$PI = "Create Temporary Table PI (Select a.Ursprungsstation, a.Vergleichsstation, a.Jaccard_PER, b.Jaccard_ICD
                FROM P_J a
                LEFT JOIN I_J b
                on (a.Ursprungsstation = b.Ursprungsstation
                AND a.Vergleichsstation = b.Vergleichsstation)
                ORDER BY Ursprungsstation, Vergleichsstation
                Limit 100)
                UNION
                (Select a.Ursprungsstation, a.Vergleichsstation, a.Jaccard_PER, b.Jaccard_ICD
                FROM P_J a
                RIGHT JOIN I_J b
                on (a.Ursprungsstation = b.Ursprungsstation
                AND a.Vergleichsstation = b.Vergleichsstation)
                ORDER BY Ursprungsstation, Vergleichsstation
                Limit 100);
                ";


                $CreatePI = mysqli_query($conn, $PI);

$PIO =  "Create Temporary Table PIO (Select a.Ursprungsstation, a.Vergleichsstation, a.Jaccard_PER, a.Jaccard_ICD, b.Jaccard_OPS
                FROM PI a
                LEFT JOIN O_J b
                on (a.Ursprungsstation = b.Ursprungsstation
                AND a.Vergleichsstation = b.Vergleichsstation)
                ORDER BY Ursprungsstation, Vergleichsstation
                Limit 100)
                UNION
                (Select a.Ursprungsstation, a.Vergleichsstation, a.Jaccard_PER, a.Jaccard_ICD, b.Jaccard_OPS
                FROM PI a
                RIGHT JOIN O_J b
                on (a.Ursprungsstation = b.Ursprungsstation
                AND a.Vergleichsstation = b.Vergleichsstation)
                ORDER BY Ursprungsstation, Vergleichsstation
                Limit 100);
                ";  

                $CreatePIO = mysqli_query($conn, $PIO);     

$PIOM =     "Create Temporary Table PIOM (Select a.Ursprungsstation, a.Vergleichsstation, a.Jaccard_PER, a.Jaccard_ICD, a.Jaccard_OPS, b.Jaccard_ML
                FROM PIO= a
                LEFT JOIN M_J b
                on (a.Ursprungsstation = b.Ursprungsstation
                AND a.Vergleichsstation = b.Vergleichsstation)
                ORDER BY Ursprungsstation, Vergleichsstation
                Limit 100)
                UNION
                (Select a.Ursprungsstation, a.Vergleichsstation, a.Jaccard_PER, a.Jaccard_ICD, a.Jaccard_OPS, b.Jaccard_ML
                FROM PIO a
                RIGHT JOIN M_J b
                on (a.Ursprungsstation = b.Ursprungsstation
                AND a.Vergleichsstation = b.Vergleichsstation)
                ORDER BY Ursprungsstation, Vergleichsstation
                Limit 100);
                ";  

                $CreatePIOM = mysqli_query($conn, $PIOM);   


    $Jaccard =  "Select Ursprungsstation, Vergleichsstation, Jaccard_PER, Jaccard_OPS, Jaccard_ICD, Jaccard_ML, ((IFNULL(Jaccard_PER, 0)+IFNULL(Jaccard_OPS, 0)+IFNULL(Jaccard_ICD, 0)+IFNULL(Jaccard_ML, 0))/4) as Jaccard FROM PIOM order by Jaccard desc";       
    $Abfrage = mysqli_query($conn, $Jaccard);
    $Abfrage2 = mysqli_query($conn, $Jaccard);

}
 

$j= 0;
while ($property = mysqli_fetch_field($Abfrage2)) {
    array_push($Eintraege2, $property->name);  //save those to array
}
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Abfrage2)) {
    
    foreach ($Eintraege2 as $item) {
        if ($j== 1) {
            $ST2= $row[$item];
        }
        if ($j == 6) {
            $BS2 = $row[$item];
            $BS2 = substr($BS2, 0, 5);
        }
        $j ++;
    //get items using property value
    }
 
}


$i = 0;
//showing property
echo '<table class="data-table" id= "t1">
        <tr class="data-heading">';  //initialize table tag
while ($property = mysqli_fetch_field($Abfrage)) {
    echo '<td>' . $property->name . '</td>';  //get field name for header
    array_push($Eintraege, $property->name);  //save those to array
}
echo '</tr>'; //end tr tag

//showing all data
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Abfrage)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($Eintraege as $item) {
        if ($i== 1) {
            $ST= $row[$item];
        }
        if ($i == 6) {
            $BS = $row[$item];
        }
        $i ++;
        echo '<td>' . $row[$item] . '</td>'; //get items using property value
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo "</table>";



?>
```

Comment: Your query failed. Why? We don't know since we don't see your code. Check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to find out why. It could be that you didn't move your database structure from localhost to hosted.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Please add the relevant piece of your PHP code - including your `mysqli_fetch_field`. At a guess your query failed due to a syntax error and so returned a Boolean false rather than a resultset object. You need to detect this case.

Comment: @halfer the php code doesn't seem to be the problem, the sql query fails in the case where I add the last join, I checked it with other queries, there is no problem with the database connection and the php code.

Comment: @peprumo I shortenend the query, but the purpose is to check that the value of 'IK' in the table 06_fab is the same for ve.FAB_ID and vi.FAB_ID

Comment: Your `create temporary table` also needs a semi-colon terminator.

Comment: We would need to see the PHP in order to determine where your error reporting ought to go. I wonder also whether two queries can be executed in the same string (some drivers can do this, others can't).

Comment: The create temporary table uses the Select query to create a table based on the sql query, as I said this in itself doesnt seem to be the problem, the problem only arises when I add the last join, as I mentioned, and it only happens once the Website is hosted by a webhoster and not locally using my own lampp server

Answer (score 0):

I've found the Problem myself, when joining the tables together the table becomes to big, this throws a max_join_size error that only occurs when hosted because the max_join_size on a shared hosting server is smaller compared to your localhost.